# XMLHttpRequest 405 method not allowed

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a POST request to a php file within the same folder as my JS and HTML files.

I've followed several different examples online but I get the same error every time. I've been looking around but cant figure out why it wont work when it works in exactly the same way in the examples. Please bear in mind I'm very new to this.

I can make GET requests just fine but that just picks up the whole php file as a response.

Error:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/3.4.3/server.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)
(anonymous) @ 3.4.3.js:29
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("postBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'server.php';
        var params = 'name=ivar&message=bajs';
        http.open('post', url, true);

        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                alert(http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
    })
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $post_var) {
        echo strtoupper($post_var);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Likely a dupe of [one of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=XMLHttpRequest+405+method+not+allowed+php+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: The error message is quite clear: the server (or the website) doesn't allow POST requests.

Comment: Do u know how to allow it? @Andreas

Comment: Ask the documentation/manual of your web server